# How can I make my animation play for longer than 250 Frames?

Tags: animation, workflow

I'm trying to find the settings that allow me to see longer previews of my animations when I play the animation with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

The animations default to only 250 frames long, but I'd like them to be longer. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Changing the Length of Your Animation

In order to see a longer preview of your animation, you need to make your animation itself longer. To do this, you can change end End Frame of your animation in several places:

- *Properties Editor > Render tab > Dimensions panel:* Set **End Frame** to a higher value
- *Timeline area:* Increase the **End** value
- *Timeline area:* Place the green frame cursor on the desired end frame, press <kbd>E</kbd> to set it as new **End**

**NOTE:** Changing the End frame in any of these places changes it in all the other places also

[image: Change Animation End Frame]

Comment: You can also place the time cursor in the timeline where you want and hit `E` key (to set the End Frame), and `S` key (to set the start frame).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I'll update my answer! :)

Comment: I know this question and answer is old, but I still want to post my comment. Isn't just increasing the frames is not enough? Don't you also need to bake the frames after increasing frames?