# Blender as video editor tracks out of sync

Tags: video, audio

I'm using blender as a video editor, everything is setup correctly for what I normally do.  I capture game footage with Open Broadcasting Software and upload the odd video here and there.  Blender seems awesome in almost every way but I recently switched to using Nvidia ShadowPlay to record my gameplay footage as the quality is fantastic at high bitrates with almost no penalty to performance.  The problem I have is that when I try to edit a video in Blender the audio and video tracks are out of sync.  When I view the video information in VNC while playing the raw recording the frame rate is never the same.  Each video has a slightly different frame rate.  I have the frame rate set to 60fps.  However the actual videos come out as 59.8842fps or 59.245fps.  I think this is what is causing the audio and video to be out of sync in Blender maybe?  I can input a custom frame rate but it looks like it only allows certain increments such as 59 or 59.4, or 60.  Is there any way to get these tracks to sync up so I can simple cut out the parts I don't want?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, at the bottom, AVSync is selected instead of No Sync, right?  If not, then the slightest bit of lag during playback in Blender will throw it off.  In Blender 2.77, I think it will automatically set the frame rate to match the clip...  EDIT: Perhaps [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10858/21825) will help?

Comment: I think I got it thanks.  I should probably start a new question but I'm changing an animation simple youtube intro from 24fps to 60fps.  The music in the intro plays at the right speed but the animation only lasts for the original time and hasn't changed its length with the new frame rate.  So it is rendering what appears to be VERY QUICKLY while the music it was matched to is still playing I have a black screen because the animation is over.  Is there an easy way to have the time of animation match the time the audio takes to play?

Comment: Probably best to look at Time Remapping, so the keyframes get spaced out.  It is right below the fps drop down.  Set the first one to 24, and the second to 60.