# Outputting full length of video node to scene

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, video

I've got a video node that I've applied some coloring nodes to for effects; output nodes to both composite and view; and I've added the scene into my VSE. Once I had this all configured I then configured my properties so that the End frame was correct and my output was going to mp4 and the my framerate is correct.

For whatever reason the video node is still only outputting the first 250 frames of the video clip. So if I render I get a video with the first few seconds and then the rest of the video is frozen on frame 250.

See in the screenshot how my scene spans the entire length of my video, but as you can see there is a green portion which is the 250 frames.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my animation play for longer than 250 Frames?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8913/how-can-i-make-my-animation-play-for-longer-than-250-frames)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43779/2843

Comment: @Samoth sorry didn't know the proper terms for these things, but as started all that has already been done.

Comment: @Samoth see screenshot provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you Add a Scene, the length of the strip is the same of the length of the Scene **in the moment that you added it**. So, if you change the length of the strip, the content lasts the same.

In those cases, **just delete and Add again the Scene Strip**. The new strip will work for the entire Scene's length.

Comment: Of course it's something that simple. Thank you.

Comment: It was simple but not obvious at all. I wonder if this could be reported as bug or something because this behavior is not logic. I'm glad I've helped ;)

Comment: @AntonioBuch is exactly right and @3pointedit explained it correctly. To prove their point: The attribute `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all['Scene'].frame_duration` is a read-only one which is set once the Scene is added as a Sequence Strip. To have it updated you need to readd your Scene Strip as he stated. An update operation to this attribute results in: `AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "frame_duration" from "SceneSequence" is read-only`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly a bug and I'm not sure that it's an easy fix. The strips in VSE typically don't correspond with data blocks from elsewhere in Blender, so that updates in duration (strip metadata in the VSE scene) cannot be instantly reflected in the VSE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to the new [2.77RC1](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.77/) - they [fixed](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Bug_Fixes#Sequencer) and improved some things according to the Strip usage in the VSE:

> Nested scene strip support (like metas)
>   This makes it possible to use scenes as a kind of multi-user meta-strip (with their own time), ([485ea43](http://developer.blender.org/rB485ea43)).

Comment: I tested with 2.77 RC1 and the problem is still there.